# Shell script Delimiter error

Tags: scripts

I have written below script to send mail of the o/p.

```
#!/bin/sh

input="/data/builds/i2SchedulerAutomation/Final.txt"
tmpfile="/data/builds/i2SchedulerAutomation/Final.html"

echo 'Content-Type: text/html; charset="us-ascii"' > "$tmpfile"
awk 'BEGIN{print "<html><body><table border=1>"} {print "<tr>";for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)print "<td>" $i"</td>";print "</tr>"} END{print "</table></body></html>"}' "$input" >> "$tmpfile"

/usr/bin/mail -s "i2BuildReport" Vinod.Kandikuppa@test.com <<-$tmpfile
```

While executing am getting below error:

```
./Table.sh: line 10: warning: here-document at line 9 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `$tmpfile')
```

Can someone resolve it? THanks

Comment: Even i kept the "$tmpfile" in mail am getting error. Am i missing something? I am getting mail also since the o/p is not printing. Please help

Comment: Take a look at https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html and check the last line of your script.

Comment: It looks like you're confused about the shell's redirection operators - if you're trying to redirect the contents of the temporary file to `mail`'s standard input, that would just be `< $tmpfile` (or better, `< "$tmpfile"`) not `<<-$tmpfile`